# Get all data from API in single hit - Python-Requests

Tags: python, api, python-2.7, get, python-requests

```
import requests
url = 'http://www.justdial.com/autosuggest.php?'
param = {
        'cases':'popular',
        'strtlmt':'24',
        'city':'Mumbai',
        'table':'b2c',
        'where':'',
        'scity':'Mumbai',
        'casename':'tmp,tmp1,24-24',
        'id':'2'
}
res = requests.get(url,params=param)
res = res.json()
```

though in first time hit the base url in browser then last 3 params not shown in requests query parameter but its working.

When I hit this API it return a json which contain 2 keys(total & results).
result key contain a list of dictionary(this is main data). and another key which is 'total'   contain total number of different categories available in Justdial.

in present case it is total=49 and so have to hit api 3 times because at one time api return only 24 results so (24+24+1  so we need to hit 3 times ).

my question is is there any way to get complete json at one time I mean there are 49 results so instead of hittiing api 3 times can we get all data(all 49 categories) in single hit. I've already tried so many combinations in params but not success.

Answer (score 0):

generally APIs have a `count` or `max_results` parameter -- set this on the URL and you'll get more results back.

Here's the documentation for Twitter's API `count` parameter: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Comment: really?? its not working neither `count` nor `max_results`.
I used this url with count and max_results one-by-one and tried in chrome plugin `postman` but same results(i mean 24)
http://www.justdial.com/autosuggest.php?cases=popular&strtlmt=0&city=Mumbai&table=b2c&where=&scity=Mumbai&casename=tmp,tmp1,0-24&case=tmp,tmp1,cat&id=1

Comment: check the JustDial.com API documentation, it might be named something else, or nonexistent

Answer (score 0):

Github APi requires you to retrieve the data in pages (up to 100 results per page) and the response dict has a 'links' entry with the url to the next page of results.

The code below iterates through all teams in an organisation until it finds the team it's looking for

```
    params = {'page': 1, 'per_page':100}
    another_page = True
    api = GH_API_URL+'orgs/'+org['login']+'/teams'
    while another_page: #the list of teams is paginated
        r = requests.get(api, params=params, auth=(username, password))
        json_response = json.loads(r.text)
        for i in json_response:
            if i['name'] == team_name:
                return i['id']
        if 'next' in r.links: #check if there is another page of organisations
            api = r.links['next']['url']
```